# How to set header image for all screens (UIViewControllers) in xcode interface builder?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, interface-builder

Currently, I'm implementing a simple Tabbed application and I need to show some header logo image on all screens. Obviously, the most simple way is to put an image in all xib files. Just curious are there any other options?

UPDATE: If I place an image inside window object in MainWindow.xib then it appears on all view controllers but it will not rotate. If I place an image outside the window then it will not display at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add an ImageView on the main window nib and set bg color of all your views as clearColor.

Comment: I did achieved desired functionality but I have got a problem. The image is not rotating :( Is there any ways how to configure that? I guess it might be impossible to do with this solution...

Comment: Rotating? do you mean after change of orientation?

Answer (score 1):

Make all your views (xib) have a clearColor background and a margin on top (for the header), then place your header image in your AppDelegate Object as a subview of the tabBarController:

```
UIImageView *nav=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.window.frame.size.height/24, self.window.frame.size.width, 44)];
[nav setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"header.png"]];
[self.tabBarController.view addSubview:nav];
[nav release];
```

I think this will solve the rotation problem.